# How to replace a continuous occurrence of a substring with a single substring?

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I have an html string parsed in android froom a spannable string. :-

```
<p dir="ltr"><b><b><b><b><b>qwert</b></b></b></b></b><b><b><b><b><b><b>y</b></b></b></b></b></b></p>
```

As you can see, there are multiple occurences of tags.

Now i have done hit and trials ,user methods like `replaceAll()`, but they replace all occurences.

What i want is that, when i pass a substring to find, lets say "`<b>`", and then it should replace, lets say the first five consecutive bold tags in the above string with a single "`<b>`" tag.

Any Suggestions

Required Result :- `<p dir="ltr"><b>qwert</b><b>y</b></p>`

Comment: Link does not work. I have no issue with android to html parsing. Its just that i want to process this above string and remove duplicates

Comment: What is the output you'd like to get from your sample input? What is the regex you're currently using?

Comment: I am not familiar with Matcher Class. Please see my edit. I have updated my question

Comment: why two <b> after qwert ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can try this regex then:

```
(<[^>]+>)\\1+
```

And replace with:

```
\\1
```

In code...

```
String test = "<p dir=\"ltr\"><b><b><b><b><b>qwert</b></b></b></b></b><b><b><b><b><b><b>y</b></b></b></b></b></b></p>";
String out = test.replaceAll("(<[^>]+>)\\1+", "$1");
```

Output:

```
<p dir="ltr"><b>qwert</b><b>y</b></p>
```

`(<[^>]+>)` matches and catches in group 1, the first tag that it finds.

`\\1` in the regex refers to the first captured tag. The `+` indicates unlimited repetition (well, the limit is a big number I don't think you need to worry about).

The replacement `$1` then also refers to the first captured tag.

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/QKLtdF)

Comment: I am new to this pattern thing. Your code works fine above. Can you explain me the process and all those square bracket meanings in the above patter

Comment: Okay, `<` and `>` mean these symbols themselves. `[^>]+` is a character class. It means any character except `>`, repeated at least once. If I had `[^a]+`, that would mean any character except `a`, repeated at least once. Does that help? Is there more you want to ask about?

Comment: Yes. Thanks, If my string has this :- `<b><i><b><i><b>`. Can i pattern match alternate "<b>" and replace them ?

Comment: @RahulGupta That could be a problem... which (if it works), will make your example input become: `<p dir="ltr"><b>qwert</b>y</p>` and I'm not sure that's something you want.

Answer (score 2):

you want somehting like this

find : `(<b>)\1+|(<\/b>)\2+`

replace: `\1\2`

demo here : 
http://regex101.com/r/aC6iP4